# Go through an R dataframe and increase the salary at certain conditions

Tags: r

I have this sample of my dataframe (df):

```
   age  salary 
1  25   20000
2  35   22000
3  31   23500
4  24   19200
5  27   27900
6  32   31010
```

I want to increase the salary by 11% for people who are aged above 30 and their salary is not the maximum salary in the table. I wrote this loop:

```
for(row in df){
  if (row$age > 30 & row$salary != max(df$salary)){
    row$salary = row$salary * 0.11
  }
}
```

but I get less than the salaries posted rather than an increase.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way without explicit `ifelse`. Should be one of the fastest ways to do this -

```
df$new_salary <- with(df, salary + 0.11*salary*(age > 30)*(salary != max(salary))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're experiencing problems is because in each iteration of the for loop (specifically, when going through each matching row), you're applying a transformation to the entire column. Try this instead:

```
k <- max(df$age)
df[df$age>30 & df$age<k, 'salary'] <- df[df$age>30 & df$age<k, 'salary'] * 1.11
```

Comment: Sorry, your answers also works fine, but had to choose one of the two answers. I selected that as I find it more readable. I'll upvote your answer once I get 15 reputations. Thanks.